# remove a chunk of a string

Tags: vb.net, string

Anyone know a better way to do this?

```
Dim Result1,Result2,FinalResult As String

Result1 = Left(sXMLResponse, sXMLResponse.IndexOf("<start>"))
Result2 = Mid(sXMLResponse, sXMLResponse.IndexOf("<end>"))

FinalResult =Result1 & Result2
```

Surely there is a built in String.Remove(StringOne, StringTwo) Method or something more graceful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be doing things in the old VB6 way. It is generally recommended to use the .NET functions in VB.NET, i.e. string.Substring instead of the Left/Right/Mid/etc. functions. Now it looks like you're simply trying to remove the text between  and  in a string, which can be done quite easily in one line.

```
Dim result = sXMLResponse.Substring(0, sXMLResponse.IndexOf("<start>")) & sXMLResponse.Substring(sXMLResponse.IndexOf("<end>") + 5)
```

Really it's not different to what you did, except it removes the need for temporary variables. Also note that there is a string.Remove method but would require a temporary variable for calculating the *count* parameter.

Of course you could equivalently use RegEx to remove the chunk of the string in one line, but it would be rather unnecessary for such a simple task, and certainly a good deal slower.

Comment: Ok great, just making sure there's nothing in the framework already for this. Thought I was missing an overload somewhere. Might use a combination of the solutions. Thanks

Comment: No prob. You could write your own extension method if you're using VB.NET 9.0 I suppose, but only bother if you're doing this regularly in code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution :

```
Dim stringOne as String="ae234-asd-dddddffdfdff";
Dim stringTwo as String="-asd-";

stringOne.Replace(stringTwo, String.Empty);
```

But if there are more than one stringTwo in stringOne, they are also removed in this solution

Comment: He's probably not removing a known text though.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I think Remove() would remove one string from another which is not really what you want.

You want to be able to extract a string that starts with one string and ends with another. In which case, why not write your own? Something like:

```
function extractStr (str as string, startStr as string, endStr as string) as string
    dim sPos as integer
    dim ePos as integer

    sPos = instr (str,startStr);
    ePos = instr (str,endStr);

    extractStr = str
    if ePos > 0 then
        extractStr = left (extractStr, ePos + len(endStr))
    end if
    if sPos > 0 then
        extractStr = mid (extractStr, sPos)
    end if
end
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the OP is using VB.NET (albeit in a VB6 style). Although your code may compile and work in VB.NET (it's been a long time since I wrote any VB6), it is not the recommended way to perform the task.

Comment: Why do you think OP is using .NET?

Comment: Oh, I meant to say that the IndexOf function only exists in .NET (as part of the System.String class). The VB6 equivalent is the InStr function, which you use in your post.